# Ruby date cutoff in Time.parse()

Tags: ruby, datetime

Ruby's `Time.parse()` works for dates from Dec 14 1901 up Jan 18 2038  (this appears to be system dependent):

```
# works
irb(main):038:0> Time.parse('14-12-1901')
=> Sat Dec 14 00:00:00 -0600 1901

# doesn't work
irb(main):039:0> Time.parse('13-12-1901')
ArgumentError: time out of range
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/time.rb:184:in `local'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/time.rb:184:in `make_time'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/time.rb:243:in `parse'
    from (irb):39
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/date/format.rb:214
```

I can't think of the reason why it stops working there. Why the odd cut-off? How can I programatically get the valid range?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby's `Time` class is a wrapper around `time_t`, which uses a signed int to represent seconds since the beginning of the Unix epoch. With a 32-bit int, this causes the 1901-2038 boundaries you're experiencing. This is often referred to as the [Y2038 bug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem).

PHP actually suffers from this same bug, so while this is a weird source for answering a Ruby question, here's an except from the PHP manual:

> The valid range of a timestamp is typically from Fri, 13 Dec 1901 20:45:54 UTC to Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 UTC. (These are the dates that correspond to the minimum and maximum values for a 32-bit signed integer.) Additionally, not all platforms support negative timestamps, therefore your date range may be limited to no earlier than the Unix epoch.

According to [this article](http://www.developer.com/features/article.php/3899806/Ruby-192-Boasts-Production-Ready-Update-as-Rails-30-Approaches.htm), Ruby 1.9.2 should fix this issue (and Rails accounts for it as well).

Alternately, you can use the [`DateTime`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/DateTime.html) class, which is able to parse the dates you're having issues with:

```
DateTime.parse('13-12-1901').strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
=> "1901-12-13"
```

Comment: Ah it all makes sense now. 2038-1902 ~= 136 years ~= 4.29 x 10^9 seconds ~= 2^32.